# C how to insert a value in to a two dimenssion array

Tags: c

I have the following code which is driving me nuts. I am trying to input values into a 2-dimensional array.

1. I do not really know how I can insert a value in to specific location in the array. For example I want to enter the values in a pyramid fashion. I should be able to add one more value in each level.

   ```
   a[0][0]                     ===>          1
   a[1][0] & [1][1]  &[1][2]   ===>         2 3
   a[2][0] & [2][0]  & [2][2]   ===>       4 5 6  etc.
   ```
2. I also want to be able to store the greatest integer In each level so that I can sum all the large integers in each level.

So far with the following code, I am unable to figure out how to insert the value and I also cannot sum the greatest values in each level.

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(j = 0; j <= 4; j++){
        printf("Enter the values in to the array");
        scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(j = 0; j <= 4; j++){
        if(arr[i][j] > arr[i][j+1]){
            holder = arr[i][j];
        }else{
            holder = arr[i][j+1];
        }
    }
    sum = sum+holder;
}

printf("%d\n\n",sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter the values in a pyramid fashion & calculate the sum of the largest numbers of each row, try the code below:

```
int arr[5][10];
int i,j;
int holder=0;
int sum = 0;

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  for(j=0; j<=i;j++)
  {
     printf("Enter your input: \n");
     scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
     if(arr[i][j] > holder)
      {
         holder = arr[i][j];
      }
  }
 printf("Largest Value in Row %d is %d\n", i, holder);
 sum = sum + holder;
 holder = 0;
}
printf(" Sum = %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: -1: Because I do not think one should post nontrivial (wrt questioner) code without any explanation. You give him/her a fish instead of showing how to fish, and he/she will come back when the requirements only slightly change.

Comment: i still have one more problem. Is that the code will keep on iterating on the first array as long as there is a value is coming in. I want it to only accept one value less than the last one. That means pyramid. For example 
  1 
 2 3 
4 5 6 
it should not take more than one value in the beginning and every array comes next should only be able to store one value > then the previous one if any one tryies to do this it should not be possible.
1 1                                                                2 3 
4 5 6  etc. 

Your co-operation is highly appreciated.for

Comment: @Jay: Remember my comment on him coming back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774284/arranging-2-dimensional-array-content

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below for dynamically deciding the array size and assigning the values:-

```
int **arr;
int *greatest_each_lavel;
int n, i, j, temp;
printf ("enter the level.\n");
scanf ("%d", &n);

if (n<1)
{
  printf ("Wrong input.\n");
  exit (1);
}
greatest_each_level = (int *) malloc (n * sizeof (int));
arr = (int **) malloc (n * sizeof (int *));
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
  arr[i] = (int *) malloc (i * sizeof (int));
}
// Populate the array members.
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  temp = 0;
  for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
  {
    printf ("Enter the number  ");
    scanf ("%d", &arr[i][j]);
    if (arr[i][j] > k)
    {
      temp = arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  greatest_each_level[i] = temp;
}

// To get the sum of greatest number at each level
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  sum = sum + greatest_each_level[i];
printf ("Sum is : %d\n", sum);

// When all task are done, dont forget to free the memory.
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  free (arr[i]);
}
free (arr);
free (greatest_each_level);
greatest_each_level = NULL;
arr = NULL;
```